# How to take out special characters out of a phrase then put them back?

Tags: java, joptionpane, replaceall

```
public static String keepLetters(String word){
    String lettersOnly = ""; //variable for letters only

    //loop to go to throught the whole code
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i = i + 1){
      char letter = word.charAt(i);  // get the ascii code
      int ascii = (int)letter;

      // check if the letter is A to Z
      if (ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90 || ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122 ){
        lettersOnly = lettersOnly + letter; // keep it if it is
      }}
    return lettersOnly; // return just the letters
}

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
     String input = "", justLetters = "";

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word or phrase");

    justLetters = keepLetters(input);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The phrase with only letters is: " + justLetters);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Why not just use input again?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's good that you provided your code, could you please tell us *what your question is*?

Comment: I want to take out special charcters(@#$%) out of the word, change the word and then at the end put them back in the word.